# Function Similar to Lambert $W$ Function

Tags: asymptotics, special-functions, lambert-w

It is known how to solve equations of the form $e^{-cx}=a_0(x-r)$ in terms of the Lambert $W$-function. Namely, according to Wikipedia, the solution is given by 
$$
x=r+\frac{1}{c}W\bigg(\frac{ce^{-cr}}{a_0}\bigg).
$$

Is there a similar way to solve equations of the form
$$
e^{-cx^2}=a_0(x-r),
$$
where say $a_0,c,r>0$? In this case, there is indeed a unique solution with positive $x$ value, for the left hand side is positive and the right hand side is linear and increasing in $x$ and is negative at $x=0$. Without the $r$, one could reduce to the above solution by squaring. I'd be interested in if there are either special functions that are reasonably well-understood to solve this, or if there are any reasonable approximations on the value of $x$ in terms of $c,a_0,$ and $r$. Thanks!

Comment: Well, the $r=0$ case reduces to the Lambert function if we square both sides. The general case is similar to generalized Lambert functions that invert $R(x)e^x$ for a rational $R$, except here it is only rational in $\sqrt{x}$. Did this come up in an application?

Comment: No, this is not solvable.

Comment: @J.G Solution [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4763432/equations-similar-to-lambert-w-with-quadratic-exponents/4763539#4763539) using Hermite polynomials. Is an answer still wanted?